# How to run a single query in mySQL combining two queries using php?

Tags: php, mysql

In my mySQL Database  i have two tables.

**t_region** and **t_city**, where i save the cities and the regions they belong.
The structure is very simple. Here is an example:

The table t_region

[image]

and the table t_city

[image]

To get a list of cities i run the query:

```
SELECT * FROM %st_city ', DB_TABLE_PREFIX
```

and save the results in an array.

The same for regions. The query is:

```
SELECT * FROM %st_region ', DB_TABLE_PREFIX
```

What i want is to create a single query in php, so i can get a list of cities names and the regions they belong, so the results will be something like that:

**Los Angeles(California), Miami(Florida)** etc

Comment: Use a SQL `JOIN`, which should be explained in any SQL tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a simple `JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.*, r.s_name
FROM  t_region r
INNER JOIN t_city c ON c.fk_i_region = r.pk_i_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with inner join both tables

```
SELECT t_city.s_name, t_region.s_name
FROM t_city
INNER JOIN t_region ON t_city.fk_i_region=t_region.pk_i_id;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a subquery, for one field is more fast than use join

```
select *,(select s_name from t_region where t_region.pk_i_id=t_city.fk_i_region) as region from t_city
```